# Equation $\frac {x^2-x-6}{x^2+x -2} - \frac {2x-4}{x-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to answer the problem as to how to show $\dfrac {x^2-x-6}{x^2+x -2} - \dfrac {2x-4}{x-1} = -1$

I have the key with the answer; the left-hand side is supposed to reduce to $ -1$ and have confirmed this is correct but which steps do I take to reach that answer?

Comment: @Robert Badea, the problem and its answer (from the separate key) have been presented in the exact way they are presented in the source. There is nothing to the right of $=$ in the source, that is where the answer (-1) is to be put.

Comment: @Robert Why not delete the comment then?

Comment: Note that though this identity is formally true, it is sometimes important to note that the function on the left-hand side is not defined when $x=1, -2$

Comment: That's true, @Mark, and hence makes it possible to cancel the common factor $x+2$, and in the end, $x - 1$. No problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$\dfrac{x^2 - x - 6}{x^2 + x-2} = \frac{(x-3)(x+2)}{(x+2)(x - 1)} = \frac {x-3}{x-1}$$

Now, we have a common denominator: $$\frac{(x-3)}{(x-1)} - \frac{2x-4}{(x-1)}=$$ $$= \frac{(x-3) - (2x-4)}{(x-1)} = $$  $$ = \dfrac{-x+1}{x-1} = \dfrac{-(x-1)}{x-1} = -1$$

Comment: Easier would be to reduce the fraction by $(x+2)$.

Comment: I've done that, my friend.

Comment: I mean before finding the common denominator. In the first line.

Comment: I can follow much of what you have done here but to me, in the very first step, it is not obvious how you concluded to rewrite $x^2-x-6$ to $(x-3)(x+2)$ and $x^2+x-2$ to $(x+2)(x-1)$. I see why you did it and now that you've already done it I can see that it is correct but it is not something that I would come up with myself. What method/reasoning lies behind rewriting that correctly? (i.e I am asking how to do it, not why to do it as I can see the rest of the problem becomes easy afterwards)

Comment: For factoring, e.g. $x^2 -x -6$ we look for two rational numbers $\alpha, \beta$ such that $\alpha\cdot \beta = -6$ (-6 is the constant coefficient of the quadratic) and $\alpha + \beta = -1$ (-1 is the coefficient of $x$). Note that $-3 \cdot 2 = -6$ and $-3 + 2 = -1$. That gives us that $(x-3)(x+2) = x^2 + (-3+2)x + (-3\cdot 2) = x^2 -x -6$. Note, that you can also use the quadratic formula to find the zeros of the quadratic. Given any zero, $x_0$, it follows that $x - x_0$ is a factor of the quadratic.

Comment: With practice, factoring becomes easier, to the point that given "nice" quadratics, you can virtually factor by inspection.

Comment: I never learned factoring and still cannot really follow the first part of your comment. I see that it works but would not be able to pull it of myself. However I now solved the problem using the helpful fact you posted that $x-x_0$ is a factor of the quadratic which is something I have used in the past. In a context without calculator and limited time, the two factors for each expression can easily be found in this (easy) case by plugging in a few integers as $x$ and from there the rest of what you posted in your answer can be done to reach the answer to the problem.